# Dos the multiple instance of the same MovieClip share the Cache?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

If I have one MovieClip which has two frame, each frame has a 1K Bitmap.

When I create three instance of this MovieClip, Is these three instance share the same memory which will only cost 2K memory or they has their own memory which will cost 2K * 3 memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will each use a new portion of memory. If you filled a room with 50 people, you would have to use more of your memory to remember each of their names. Though in flash each of the MovieClips may not have different names, they do have other properties which make them unique.

For example, each MovieClip would have it's own position in the DisplayList, x, y, etc etc etc.